# "new" keyword on static method call

Tags: java

I don't understand the "new" keyword in this static method call. What is it's purpose. NetBeans underlines .net if I delete it with a message of "cannot find symbol"

```
String translated =  new java.net.URI(url).getPath();
```

I'm certain that this is a basic question that has been answered before, however all of my searches come up with information on creating objects and is not applicable.

Thank You

Comment: `java.net.URI` is the *full qualified name* of the class. You usually shorten the classes name by adding an *import* line for the package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not a `static` method call, you're just instantiating an object of type `URI` and calling the `getPath()` method on it. The `java.net.` part is explicitly inlining the fully qualified class name, it's the same as this:

```
// at the start of your class
import java.net.URI;

// in your method
String translated = new URI(url).getPath();
```